# How to split database schema in Realm?

Tags: realm

I need to have two different schema in one app using realm db.
It seems that should work below solution:

```
   open class AModel : RealmObject() {
     var a: Int = 0
   }
   open class BModel : RealmObject() {
     var b: Int = 0
   }
   open class XModel : RealmObject() {
     var x: Int = 0
   }
   open class YModel : RealmObject() {
     var y: Int = 0
   }

@RealmModule(classes = [AModel::class,BModel::class])
open class Schema1

val conf1 = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
  .name("db1.realm")
  .schemaVersion(1)
  .modules(Schema1())
  .build();

@RealmModule(classes = [XModel::class,YModel::class])
open class Schema2

val conf2 = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
  .name("db2.realm")
  .schemaVersion(2)
  .modules(Schema2())
  .build();
```

but when app starts and calls `Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(conf1)`, it prints below error:

```
com.example.XModel  is not part of the schema for this Realm
```

So it seems that I miss something in configuration but looking at docs I cannot figure out what. So what I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you set the schema version of `conf2` as a second version, but the first one was never created. Change it for this:

```
...

val conf2 = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
  .name("db2.realm")
  .schemaVersion(1)
  .modules(Schema2())
  .build();
```